# Play framework, template html won't update

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, spray, twirl

I feel silly asking this, but I cannot isolate what's causing this issue.

The templating framework has worked fine for me up until now.

- Copied a .idea project to a new dir, deleted workspace.xml and changed .name (basically "forking" a Play project i had previously)
- run activator and load localhost:9000, everything works fine.
- Open main.scala.html in intellij (my primary template) and change

`<ul>
   <li><a href="@routes.PrismicMain.index()">blog</a></li>
 </ul>`

To:

`<ul>
    <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="@routes.PrismicMain.index()">blog</a></li>
 </ul>`

- Hard reload page

Nothing shows up. Check the markup, no new elements. Nothing in my CSS or jquery that would remove them from the flow either (i tried adding multiple different elements that didnt show up). I then went on to check some of the pages loaded within the templates and updates to those worked fine. Verified that im running Activator from the right dir and editing the right project. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: it would appear the issue has something to do with this: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3608

Comment: Have you tried `sbt clean` respectively `activator clean`?